# How to use Rhapsody from Jenkins to generate code - Facing License issue

Tags: jenkins, rhapsody

I am trying to generate code from RhapsodyCL using a batch script. When I run this batch script using cmd, the code is generated just fine but when I try to generate code via Jenkins I am getting error in the Jenkins build output which I think is because of trying to start RhapsodyCL due to 'license not found'.

The error in Jenkins console output looks like:

```
11:33:10 C:\Test>rhapsodyCL.exe -f C:\Test1\Test-BitBucket\script.bat 
11:33:13 
11:33:13 C:\Test>exit -1
```

-1 is the rhapsody return code for license not found.

So is this a Jenkins issue that it can not find the Rhapsody license ? Or is it something else ?

Answer (score 0):

There are not many details in your question but rhapsody code generation via jenkins has worked for me in the past so:

Is it rhapsody installed for All Users in the jenkins machine?

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Yes it is installed for all the accounts. I even checked it system application and that is running fine but still no luck in getting the license. I am wondering is it actually a license issue.

Comment: more questions: can you run again RhapsodyCL with the -verbose flag (to get more error details)? when you mention you ran it succesfully via cmd, it was on the Jenkins node, right?

Comment: Yes it was on the same computer that of Jenkins server. I will try with the verbose as well. Many thanks